# Getting Error-500 Error-524 -after loging to Osclass oc-admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, osclass

So many times I am getting 500 and 524 errors. sometimes I get these messages
also while working on osclass admin panel.

Warning: mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in /home/u120222170/domains/pinposter.com/public_html/oc-includes/osclass/classes/database/DBCommandClass.php on line 1011

I have tried to sort out the issue from hosting provider but could not resolve the issue and guided me to sort out through developers from stack overflow

```
function _execute($sql)
{
   return $this->connId->query($sql);
}


Error 524 Ray ID: 5289936d6ba0a5b8 • 2019-10-20 08:21:02 UTC
A timeout occurred
```

Error log file:

```
[20-Oct-2019 16:34:53 Asia/Dili] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in /home/u120222170/domains/pinposter.com/public_html/oc-includes/osclass/classes/database/DBCommandClass.php on line 1011
[20-Oct-2019 16:34:53 Asia/Dili] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function numRows() on boolean in /home/u120222170/domains/pinposter.com/public_html/oc-includes/osclass/model/Admin.php:63
```